# Running Windows phone 7 app in background

Tags: windows-phone-7, windows-phone

I want a part(Service) in my windows phone app to run periodically.Actually its a server request , which should be made periodically and show any changes to user as notification

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use the [PeriodicTask](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/hh202942%28v=vs.105%29.aspx) which runs every 30 minutes in the background unless the user has not forbidden that. Notify the user about changes with a [ShellToast](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/windowsphone/develop/microsoft.phone.shell.shelltoast%28v=vs.105%29.aspx) or think about Push Notifications.

**Important:** Please keep in mind, that you can *never* rely on background tasks in Windows Phone. There are many reasons why such a task will not run. So do not outsource necessary or important work to it.